# how to increment inside tuple in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose that I have tuples of the form
`[(('d',0),('g',0)),(('d',0),('d',1)),(('i',0),('g',0))]`

Then how do I increment the numbers inside the tuple that they are of the form:-
`[(('d',1),('g',1)),(('d',1),('d',2)),(('i',1),('g',1))]`

?

I am able to do this in a single for loop. But I am looking for shorter methods.

P.S. You are allowed to create new tuples

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A list comprehension will do the trick:

```
>>> t = [(('d',0),('g',0)),(('d',0),('d',1)),(('i',0),('g',0))] 

>>> print([tuple((a, b+1) for a, b in group) for group in t])

   [[('d', 1), ('g', 1)], [('d', 1), ('d', 2)], [('i', 1), ('g', 1)]]
```

Comment: For newer Python versions 3+, `print` requires parentheses:
`print( [tuple((a, b + 1) for a, b in group) for group in t] )`

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the values in tuples, tuples are immutable.  You would need to make them be lists or create a new tuple with the value you you want and store that.

Comment: The tuples are in a list according to the question.

Comment: @Navith Right, but the tuples themselves still cannot be changed, it doesn't matter whether or not they are in a list

Comment: You are allowed to create new tuples and store them

Comment: But you can change the list (through `[:] =`) to use new tuples with the second value incremented.

Comment: Please elaborate @Navith

Comment: @Navith that's what I was trying to say, what part of it doesn't say that? you cannot change the tuples, but you can "create a new tuple with the value you want and store that" as I said

Comment: Regarding the comment @Navith made about using `[:]`: a list comprehension will create a new list, so `t = [tuple((a, b+1) for a, b in group) for group in t]` will result in a new list with new tuples being assigned to `t`. However, if you use slice notation on the LHS of the assignment, and don't specify a start or stop, it will update the list in-place, i.e. `t[:] = [tuple((a, b+1) for a, b in group) for group in t]` will result in new tuples being created, but will replace the contents of `t` with the new tuples, rather than create a new list. Why would you do this? It *could* be faster.

Answer (score 2):

This is the least pythonic way but the most explanatory.

Split into lists, add values to the integer list, then zip them back together:

```
valued = []
lettered = []
plusone = []
listed = [(('d',0),('g',0)),(('d',0),('d',1)),(('i',0),('g',0))]
for x,y in listed:
    for subx, suby in x,y:
        valued.append(int(suby))
        lettered.append(subx)
for value in valued:
    value = value + 1
    plusone.append(int(value))
#print plusone
coolness = zip(lettered,plusone)
print coolness
exit()
```

The results are:
`[('d', 1), ('g', 1), ('d', 1), ('d', 2), ('i', 1), ('g', 1)]`

Comment: "I am able to do this in a single for loop. But I am looking for shorter methods." This is not shorter...

Comment: @DavidGreydanus whoops, I swear that wasn't in the question at first.